# GET latLng of my searched places while ng-click show on map in Native Browser

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova

My query is that i had developed an app using Phonegap & AngularJS and have stucked at one point as i am new to this i am not able to get the lat & long of my searched places on native browser. I have fetched the details of my nearby places through foursquare api and listed in my app and its working fine in my app when i click on button SHOW ON MAP the location is perfect but when i want to show it on native browser it points to the current position of my. even i click on my searched location button then too.
For eg, I am searching the nearby country location of some xyz company when i want to check the locaion on map through native browser of Japan country it shows the wrong location. it shows the details of my location as india which is not right. i have to get the pointer to the japan country so please help me out in this query
I am building this app on Android using phonegap plugins.

```
HTML Code:
<button class="button icon-left ion-location" ng-click="myData.doClick()">Show on Map</button>

App.js Code:

app.controller('dataController', function($scope,$http,$window){ 
    var app = this;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.position = position;
          console.log($scope.position.coords);
            http.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?'+$scope.position.coords.latitude+','+$scope.position.coords.longitude+'&query=XXXXXXX').success(function(data){
            app.api = data.response.venues;
          })
        });
      });
    }
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.doClick = function() {
     $window.navigator.app.loadUrl('https://maps.google.com/maps/?q='+$scope.position.coords.latitude+','+$scope.position.coords.longitude, { openExternal:true });}
 });
```

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: $scope.position = position; Is your physical location using -i guess- your internet connection information. When you doClick, you give as get data to google map your current position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution just in place of $window.navigator.app.loadUrl('') i have used geo code which used to point latlng to the native browser for further tutorial refer to [click here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/launching-external-maps-application) hope so it will guide you too.